# Access multidimensional list value by tuple of indices in python

Tags: python, multidimensional-array

I have a complex multidimensional utterable object (say, list). I want to write function to access the value of an element represented by tuple of indices. The number of dimensions is itself variable. It should also return `None` if the element does not exist:

```
l = [[[1, 2],
      [3, 4]],
     [[5, 6],
      [7, 8]]]
access(l, (0, 0, 0)) # prints 1
access(l, (0, 1, 1)) # prints 4
access(l, (1, 1)) # prints [7, 8]
access(l, (0, 1, 2)) # prints None
access(l, (0, 0, 0, 0)) # prints None
```

How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it using [`reduce()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#reduce):

```
def access(obj, indexes):
    return reduce(lambda subobj, index: subobj[index] if isinstance(subobj, list) and index < len(subobj) else None, indexes, obj)
```

Or as pointed by @chepner, you can use `def` to make it more readable:

```
def access(obj, indexes):
    def _get_item(subobj, index): 
        if isinstance(subobj, list) and index < len(subobj):
            return subobj[index]
        return None

    return reduce(_get_item, indexes, obj)
```

Comment: I think you've gotten to the point where it's worth switching from a `lambda` expression to a `def` statement.

Comment: Alternatively, it might be simpler to leave out the error checking and edge cases, and just return `None` on any exception. This allows you to just pass `list.__getitem__` as the reducer.

Answer (score 2):

An alternate approach to Yaroslav's answer, in which you ask forgiveness rather than permission before indexing the list:

```
def access(obj, indexes):
    try:
        return reduce(list.__getitem__, indexes, obj)
    except Exception:
        return None
```

It's not as foolproof; it make the assumption that `access` will be used as intended, and you don't mind getting `None` back if someone decides to try `access(1, 1)`, for example.

Answer (score 2):

It's not a great deal harder to do as chepner suggests, but a bit more carefully. Return `None` only if the exception is `IndexError` and what is tried is more specific. Something like

```
def access(obj, indexes):
    a = obj
    for i in indexes:
       try: 
           a = a[i]
       except IndexError:
           return None
       # except TypeError:
           # when you try to index deeper than the object supports

    # a  is not constrained to be a scalar, it may still be dimensional
    # if insufficient indexes were passed.
    return a
```

BTW this will work if at some levels you have a dict not a list. ie

```
x = access(obj, (3, 'default', 'range', 1))
```

will work for an appropriate object, will throw an exception if one or two levels down is not a dict or doesn't have the key. I've used something very like this for accessing `JSON.load` results. You might want also to return `None` on `KeyError` which is the dict equivalent of `IndexError`.

You add tests such as `isinstance(a, list)` or `hasattr(a, '__iter__')` to make even more sure that you are indexing what was intended.

Comment: that should be hasattr ... comma quote underscore underscore iter ... Didn't notice when I posted and don't know markup well enough to fix

Comment: You can use ` to mark inline code. I did that for you here.